# voltage sources in parallel without any resistors

Tags: dc

![two dc voltage sources are in parllel & they are grounded.so what reading voltmeter will show?
][two dc voltage sources of different voltage are in parllel & they are grounded.so what reading voltmeter will show?]

Comment: What is the "![" about?

Comment: Closing since this is just homework dumped on us. The crappy formatting and lack of respect it shows also encourages me to dispense with this question expediently instead of trying to find a way to salvage it. *Screw this.*

Answer (score 1):

If they are ideal voltage sources then the answer is not defined, it's not allowed.

If they are real world voltage sources then each will have some finite output impedance which will act as a voltage divider between the two sources giving a voltage somewhere in between.  This assumes that the lower value supply can sink current and one or the other doesn't shut down due to over-voltage or over-current protection.

Many supplies can't sink current, so the lower value supply might just be pulled up close to the higher value supply.  It all depends on the design and protection features of the particular supplies involved.

Comment: John D. - Very well stated !